# How to index a comma separated text column using Oracle text

Tags: oracle

I have a column with comma separated numbers like '2323,23323,23323' . The table has 20 million records and takes about 37 secs to return a result based on a like keyword like below .

```
SELECT count(*) from testtable WHERE node_sequence like '%324%';
```

I tried to improve the query time by using oracle text by creating the below index

```
CREATE INDEX node_sequence_index ON testtable(node_sequence) INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context;
exec ctx_ddl.sync_index('node_sequence_index');
```

But the below query works only with words:

```
SELECT count(*) from testtable WHERE CONTAINS(node_sequence, '324') > 0;
```

By looking at the documentation , the indexing will tokenize by words (Separated by space) . Is there a way to tokenize by comma ? I have not been able to find a sample where this can be done .Please help me understand  what am I missing here ?

Comment: You could add a string replacement function on node_sequence to get rid of the comma.

Comment: Yes, but I want to see if this is possible without replacing the comma. Replacing will cause a lot of changes in the referenced places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create and tune your own lexer with desired parameters([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cdatadic.htm#i1007615)).

Something like this(sorry, not tested):

```
begin
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('comma_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('comma_lexer', 'PRINTJOINS', '''()/^&"');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('comma_lexer', 'PUNCTUATIONS', ',.-?!');
end;
/

create index node_sequence_index 
  on testtable(node_sequence)
  indextype is ctxsys.context 
  parameters ('lexer comma_lexer')
;
```

**Update**

Code from comment by @Chandan which works for conditions mentioned in the question:

```
begin 
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('comma_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('comma_lexer', 'WHITESPACE', ',');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('comma_lexer', 'NUMGROUP', '#'); 
end; 
/

create index node_sequence_index 
  on testtable(node_sequence) 
  indextype is ctxsys.context 
  parameters ('lexer comma_lexer')
;
```

Comment: begin
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('comma_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('comma_lexer', 'WHITESPACE', ',');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('comma_lexer', 'NUMGROUP', '#');
end;

create index node_sequence_index 
  on testtable(node_sequence)
  indextype is ctxsys.context 
  parameters ('lexer comma_lexer');

Comment: The above code in the comment worked for me . I had to replace the NUMGROUP with an arbitrary value like '#' since the string '4677,45555,45555,55555,5555' was being considered as a single number due to comma being used as a default numgroup.

Answer (score 0):

```
begin 
  ctx_ddl.create_preference('IDX_search', 'BASIC_LEXER');
  ctx_ddl.set_attribute('IDX_search', 'startjoins', ',');
end; 

CREATE INDEX FGK.IDX_CALC_UIDS_search 
  ON tbl_HISTORY (search) indextype 
  is ctxsys.context parameters('lexer IDX_search sync(on commit)');
```